# How to tell if oplocks are enabled on the server

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

I am troubleshooting a problem with network file access.
I have a network share on a Windows 2003 server, I need to know whether opportunistic locking (oplocks) is enabled or not in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296264/en-us) :

> The location of the client registry entry for opportunistic locking
>   has changed from the location in Microsoft Windows NT. In later
>   versions of Windows, you can disable opportunistic locking by setting
>   the following registry entry to 1:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MRXSmb\Parameters\
>
> OplocksDisabled REG_DWORD 0 or 1 
>   Default: 0 (not disabled) Note The OplocksDisabled entry configures Windows clients to 
>   request or not to request opportunistic locks on a remote file.
>
> You can also deny the granting of opportunistic locks by setting the
>   following registry entry to 0:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
>
> EnableOplocks REG_DWORD 0 or 1 
>   Default: 1 (enabled) Note The EnableOplocks entry configures Windows-based servers to 
>   allow or to deny opportunistic locks on local files. These servers include
>   workstations that share files.